# Error Recognizing Correct Answer in a Java Quiz Program

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

My code below is designed to give the user a 25 question quiz and track how many they got correct printing out their final score at the end. On this line
`if (questionHolder.answerCorrect(candidateAnswer))` I am getting an error message that states it cannot invoke `answerCorrect` on the array type. How do I fix this issue so my program runs? I posted all code below but the class file with my error is Quiz.java Thank you!

```
//********************************************************************
//  Question.java       Author: Lewis/Loftus
//
//  Represents a question (and its answer).
//********************************************************************

public class Question 
{
   private String question, answer;


   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Constructor: Sets up the question with a default complexity.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public Question (String query, String result)
   {
      question = query;
      answer = result;

   }



   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the question.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public String getQuestion()
   {
      return question;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the answer to this question.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public String getAnswer()
   {
      return answer;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns true if the candidate answer matches the answer.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public boolean answerCorrect (String candidateAnswer)
   {
      return answer.equals(candidateAnswer);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns this question (and its answer) as a string.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public String toString()
   {
      return question + "\n" + answer;
   }
}

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Quiz

{
private int score;
private Question[] questionHolder = new Question[25];
private int numQuestions;



public Quiz()
{
this.score = 0;
this.numQuestions = 0;

}

public void addQuestion (Question Q)
{
this.questionHolder[numQuestions++] = Q;
}

public int giveQuiz()

{

Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

String candidateAnswer;


scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();


for (int i = 0; i < numQuestions; i++)
{

candidateAnswer = scan.nextLine();
if (questionHolder.answerCorrect(candidateAnswer))
score++;
}
return getscore();
}
public int getscore()
{
return score;
}
public String toString()
{
return getscore() + "\n";
}

}

public class QuizTime

{
public static void main (String[] args)

{
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Initializes the variables.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Question Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6, Q7, Q8, Q9, Q10, Q11, Q12, Q13, Q14, Q15, Q16, Q17, Q18, Q19,
Q20, Q21, Q22, Q23, Q24, Q25;

Quiz T1;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Creates the question and answer and also sets its complexity value.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Q1 = new Question ("What is the capital of Virginia?", "Richmond");

Q2 = new Question ("Is an apple a Fruit or a vegetable?", "Fruit");

Q3 = new Question ("What continent is China in?", "Asia");

Q4 = new Question ("Is Germany in Europe or South America?", "Europe");

Q5 = new Question ("What color is a black bear?", "Black");

Q6 = new Question ("What is the capital of Arizona?", "Phoenix");

Q7 = new Question ("What do cows produce??", "Milk");

Q8 = new Question ("What ocean is closest to New York City?", "Atlantic");

Q9 = new Question ("What ocean surrounds Japan?", "Pacific");

Q10 = new Question ("What is the largest state in America?", "Alaska");

Q11 = new Question ("What is the smallest state?", "Deleware");

Q12 = new Question ("What is the most populated state?", "California");

Q13 = new Question ("What is instrument did Jascha Heifetz play?", "Violin");

Q14 = new Question ("Was Mozart a composer or a computer?", "Composer");

Q15 = new Question ("What is the largest country by area?", "Russia");

Q16 = new Question ("What is the most populated country?", "China");

Q17 = new Question ("What country did Pizza originate in?", "Italy");

Q18 = new Question ("What is the last name of the first American President?", "Washington");

Q19 = new Question ("What country borders America to the south?", "Mexico");

Q20 = new Question ("What island is 700 miles off the coast of NYC?", "Bermuda");

Q21 = new Question ("What city contains the Eiffel Tower?", "Paris");

Q22 = new Question ("Who wrote Romeo and Juliet?", "Shakespeare");

Q23 = new Question ("What swims in the ocean?", "Fish");

Q24 = new Question ("What is man's best friend?", "Dog");

Q25 = new Question ("What is another name for coffee and the language of this program?", "Java");


//--------------------------------------------------------------
//Adds the questions into quiz.
//--------------------------------------------------------------
T1= new Quiz();
T1.addQuestion(Q1);
T1.addQuestion(Q2);
T1.addQuestion(Q3);
T1.addQuestion(Q4);
T1.addQuestion(Q5);
T1.addQuestion(Q6);
T1.addQuestion(Q7);
T1.addQuestion(Q8);
T1.addQuestion(Q9);
T1.addQuestion(Q10);
T1.addQuestion(Q11);
T1.addQuestion(Q12);
T1.addQuestion(Q13);
T1.addQuestion(Q14);
T1.addQuestion(Q15);
T1.addQuestion(Q16);
T1.addQuestion(Q17);
T1.addQuestion(Q18);
T1.addQuestion(Q19);
T1.addQuestion(Q20);
T1.addQuestion(Q21);
T1.addQuestion(Q22);
T1.addQuestion(Q23);
T1.addQuestion(Q24);
T1.addQuestion(Q25);

//--------------------------------------------------------------
//Prints out the quizes.
//--------------------------------------------------------------
System.out.print(T1.giveQuiz());


}
}
```

Comment: Please try to leave out unnecessary comments an spaces, it's more pleasing to the eye for readers. And use proper indentation when posting. :)

Comment: OK! Did I do a decent job at posting an SSCCE at least?

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
if (questionHolder[i].answerCorrect(candidateAnswer))
```

As `questionHolder` is an array. it will not have `answerCorrect` API. So you have to pick the question from your `questionHolder`.

Comment: Ok, no more errors but it still wont' compile. It says no main method in quiz class but the main is in the quiztime class. I can't define it again? Am i missing an implementation?

Comment: Run quiztime class not quiz class

Answer (score 1):

`answerCorrect()` is defined for `Question` type and `questionHolder` is `Question[]`

Change

```
if (questionHolder.answerCorrect(candidateAnswer))
```

to

```
if (questionHolder[i].answerCorrect(candidateAnswer))
```

Comment: Ok, no more errors but it still wont' compile. It says no main method in quiz class but the main is in the quiztime class. I can't define it again? Am i missing an implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking the method on the entire array instead of your current `Question` object.
Replace that with `questionHolder[i].answerCorrect(candidateAnswer)` and it should work

Comment: Ok, no more errors but it still wont' compile. It says no main method in quiz class but the main is in the quiztime class. I can't define it again? Am i missing an implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Change that condition to

```
if (questionHolder[i].answerCorrect(candidateAnswer))
```

Comment: Ok, no more errors but it still wont' compile. It says no main method in quiz class but the main is in the quiztime class. I can't define it again? Am i missing an implementation?

Comment: You need to run the class which has main method using java command. In your case, you need to execute `java QuizTime`

Comment: Hmm. Any idea why nothing is coming up when I launch it?

Comment: Scanner class is used in the method. Hence, I believe it is waiting for user's inputs. Try giving the inputs twice and let it run.

Comment: It seems that the method asks the user to enter the answers for all the questions. For debugging purposes, I would advice to use System.out.println statements before any scanner statement to let the user inform what the program is expecting as an input.